# retrieving number value from datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, runtime

I am trying to retrieve a numerical value from datagridview. The data type for both the value in the table, and the variable (weeklyTotal), are integer. Also I am trying to cast it into integer. I looked through the whole website for similar problems, and yet none of the solutions were helpful. The error message that I am getting is “when casting form a number, the value must be less than infinity”. I went back to my table more than one time to make sure that I don’t have invalid value.

it's a runtime error and the IDE always point at this line

**weeklyTotal += (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;**

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sdate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            ddate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            if ((weekFirstDay <= Convert.ToInt32(sdate) &&
                Convert.ToInt32(sdate) <= (weekFirstDay + 7))||(weekFirstDay <= `Convert.ToInt32(ddate) &&`
                Convert.ToInt32(ddate) <= (weekFirstDay + 7)))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                weeklyTotal += (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;

                //weeklyTotalString = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //weeklyTotal += Convert.ToInt32(weeklyTotalString);


            }
            else
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the following won't cast your cell value to the int type:

```
(int) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value
```

You're just taking the string saying "hey compiler, please treat it as an int type", but it will still be a string type underneath. Use the `Convert.ToInt32` method like you did earlier.

```
weeklyTotal += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
```

Comment: i went back to use the earlier code Convert.ToInt32. it seems working better. the reason why commented because it was show me an error message.

thank you so much. Is there is another way that converting the value from datagridview into string, then to numerical?

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["col_name"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to to an (int) cast on a DBNull value.  I'm assuming that you populating the datagridview with data from the database.

Try this:

```
if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != DBNull.Value)
{
    weeklyTotal += (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
}
```