# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' in datagridview cell values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to make sure that a value of one of my cells in my datagridview is greater than 0 to do something. but it gives me the error I mentioned.

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["totalQTYColumnDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value >= 0) {

do something

}
```

I dont know how to convert it into Int when I do this it says its wrong:

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Convert.ToInt32(Cells["totalQTYColumnDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value) >= 0) {

do something

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieving number value from datagridview C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590132/retrieving-number-value-from-datagridview-c-sharp)

Comment: You need to convert your `object` to `int`. Otherwise there is no possible comparison. The types of the objects you want to compare are different, thus can't be compared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have first parse the value as an integer and then make the compare. You can't compare an `System.Object` with an integer literal.

```
var cell = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["totalQTYColumnDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"];
int totalQTY;
if(int.TryParse(cell.Value?.ToString(), out totalQTY)
  && totalQTY >= 0)
{

}
```

Note: [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns true when parsing succeeds otherwise returns false. When parsing succeeds the parsed value is copied to `totalQTY`.

Comment: @absolute455 if the value can be `null`, I recommend `.Value?.ToString()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646145/how-can-i-extract-a-string-from-an-excel-cell/41127000#41127000

Comment: @slai what? you mean I add a question mark? what does it do?

Comment: @absolute455 This is called conditional operator. If `Value` is `null` and you call  `ToString` on it you will get a `NullReferenceException` and your program would stop unexpectedly to work - unless the corresponding code is wrapped in a `try/catch` block. Null conditional operator would save you from that and the call on `ToString` would be done only when `Value` is *not* null. For further info please have a look at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators